# Get index of ALL occurrences in a list

Tags: list, kotlin, filter

Hey I'm looking for a function to get from the list:

```
[6, 54, 3, 6, 3]
```

the following list:

```
[0, 3]
```

when I filter on 6.

So far, I've only found functions that let me filter on the first or last occurrence.

Comment: There may be more efficient methods, but this ought to work: `fun List<Int>.indicesOf(i: Int) = mapIndexed { index, elem -> if (elem == i) index else -1 }.filter { it != -1 }`

Comment: @Michael Which could be improved to: `fun Iterable<Int>.indicesOf(i: Int) = mapIndexedNotNull{ index, elem -> index.takeIf{ elem == i } }`

Comment: @Michael One of us should post an answer from this!  I'll give you first dibs… :-)

Comment: @gidds Your version is simpler, so go ahead.

Comment: Thanks guys! Great suggestions!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's currently no single function in the standard library for this, but it's easy to write your own, e.g.:

```
fun <E> Iterable<E>.indexesOf(e: E)
    = mapIndexedNotNull{ index, elem -> index.takeIf{ elem == e } }
```

This will work on any list, collection, or other iterable, of any type, and returns a `List<Int>`.  If there are no matching items (e.g. if the collection is empty), it returns an empty list.

Here [`mapIndexedNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html) transforms the elements, returning only the non-null ones.  And [`takeIf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) is used to get the index only of matching elements, returning null for the rest (which will then be discarded).

This should be relatively efficient; it does a single scan through the list, and creates only a single new list with the results.  (If temporary objects were a major concern, you'd probably not store the matching indices in a list at all, but simply loop through them with some `forEachMatchingIndex()` function instead.)

(Thanks to Michael for the initial idea.)

---

Update: for completeness, here's a version which finds elements satisfying any supplied function:

```
inline fun <E> Iterable<E>.indexesOf(predicate: (E) -> Boolean)
    = mapIndexedNotNull{ index, elem -> index.takeIf{ predicate(elem) } }
```

You could use this to e.g. find the indexes of all even numbers:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).indexesOf{ it % 2 == 0 } // [1, 3, 5]
```